# Pseudo-elements :after and :before not appearing consistently

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am creating two rectangles each with 2 colors. Rather than creating a container div and 2 seperate empty div boxes just to display color, I'm trying to use `:after` to overlay one box on top of another.

This is a learning process for me. So after I get it to work on the containers, I will attempt to add the two colors to `:before` and `:after` on the text objects themselves, and compare the process/results. Unfortunately I am so far unable to display the `:after` pseudo-elements in the container div.

Here's my prototype:
[image]

---

Here's what I've got so far:
[image]

```
#aprende_heading_container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #1b414a;
  height: 102px;
}

#aprende_heading_container:after {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.29);
}

#aprende_subheading_container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #358394;
  height: 100px;
}

#aprende_subheading_container:after {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `before` and `after` should have `content` and `display` attributes:

```
#aprende_subheading_container:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

I'm assuming you're trying to give your elements that two-tone effect with these pseudo elements? You should consider using [gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) for that. You could use a [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create them.

Comment: Thanks for answering. About the gradients: Great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to used `content: '';` in your pseudo-elements? `:after` and `:before`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yea, I tried to comment on his post, but I didnt have reputation enough to do it.
thanks!